# Angular2: How to make sure the execution will be run in order line by line?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular2 Navbar Component which includes a logout button:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

    loggedIn: boolean;

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router : Router) {
        if(localStorage.getItem('PortalAdminHasLoggedIn') == '') {
            this.loggedIn = false;
        } else {
            this.loggedIn = true;
        }
    }

    logout(){
        this.loginService.logout().subscribe(
            res => {
                localStorage.setItem('PortalAdminHasLoggedIn', '');
            },
            err => console.log(err)
            );

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        location.reload();
    }

    getDisplay() {
    if(!this.loggedIn){
      return "none";
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

What I expect when clicking the logout button is firstly the logout() function in the LoginService will be executed then set the localStorage variable, then nagivate to the login component and reload the page.

But what I realize is sometime the page will be reloaded before executing the logout() function in the LoginService, so this will not set new value for the localStorage. How can I correct the code so that it will be executed in order?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend you read up on how to deal with RxJS and observables, or you'll have a tough time in Angular. Those methods are *asynchronous*, you can't get it to run line by line (as with promises and callbacks before observables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you execute any asynchronous process, such as your logout, the code will *not* be executed in order. The argument to the `.subscribe` method is actually a callback method that will be called back at some undefined future time. So the only way to ensure that code is executed only after this is complete is to call that code from **within** the subscribe method.

```
logout(){
    this.loginService.logout().subscribe(
        res => {
            localStorage.setItem('PortalAdminHasLoggedIn', '');
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            location.reload();  // <-- what is this for?
        },
        err => console.log(err)
        );


}
```

And I'm curious what the `location.reload()` is for. You should not need to reload after navigating?

Comment: hi DeborahK, thank you for your solution. I put the location.reload() there because I would like to reload the page after navigating, if not it just navigate without refreshing the page

Comment: I've not seen that done before. Do you really need to reload the entire page? Could you instead just reload the data for the page? This seems to go against the idea of a SPA?

Comment: actually what i mean here is when the user logout, everything will be clear and the page will be refreshed also